# Where should I put my property without violating the MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

I am new to Xamarin and the MVVM pattern and I have a simple application that should display contacts in a list.

Now my view displays the contacts lastname and its number. Okay, great! Now I would like to have Lastname and Surname displayed. Sure I could modify my model to hold a property of something called `public string FullName` and fill that. But I guess thats not in the spirit of the pattern, right?

Where should I reflect something like this without violating the pattern? Only within view and the XAML file by using something like `<MultiBinding />`? Or should my ViewModel hold additional properties?

This is my code:

**Model:**

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ContactsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    public Command LoadContacts { get; set; } 

    public ContactsViewModel()
    {
        this.Title = "List of contacts";
        Contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
        LoadContacts = new Command(async () => await LoadContactsFromDataStore());
    }

    private async Task LoadContactsFromDataStore()
    {
        var contacts = await ContactDataStore.GetItemsAsync(true);

        foreach (var contact in contacts)
        {
            Contacts.Add(contact);
        }
    }
}
```

And my base class

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public IContactDataStore<Contact> ContactDataStore => DependencyService.Get<IContactDataStore<Contact>>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="New Contact" Clicked="AddContact_Clicked"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="ContactsListView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              HasUnevenRows="True"
              ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Lastname}" FontSize="16"></Label>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Number}" FontSize="13"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>            
</StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
[DesignTimeVisible(false)]
public partial class ContactsPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly ContactsViewModel contactsViewModel;

    public ContactsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = contactsViewModel = new ContactsViewModel();
    }

    private async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!(args.SelectedItem is Contact contact))
            return;

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ContactDetailPage(new ContactDetailViewModel(contact)));

        ContactsListView.SelectedItem = null;
    }

    private async void AddContact_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (contactsViewModel.Contacts.Count == 0)
        {
            contactsViewModel.LoadContacts.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just my personal opinion: I'd go with a [Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data) because it will leave room for special conditions you need to cater for.

Comment: Personally, I see nothing wrong with having a read-only "getter" for a FullName which returns the individual parts in whatever format you want... last, first or first last, etc.  As long as you are not allowing edit to this combined field.

Comment: You have so much violations here, you should not think about this one :o)

Comment: @SirRufo Where do you see other violations? The code I've posted is basically Microsofts `Xamarin Tabbed Template` slightly modified

Comment: **1.** Hard coded dependencies ContactDataStore in ViewModelBase should be injected by DI **2.** Hard coded dependency for BindingContext in ContactsPage **3.** Application logic inside view (navigating, adding, loading)

Comment: BTW Who states the MS templates are good MVVM examples? Even within the big samples they use a [Locator](https://github.com/microsoft/SmartHotel360-Mobile/blob/master/Source/SmartHotel.Clients/SmartHotel.Clients/ViewModels/Base/Locator.cs) which is a code smell and should be avoided - and MS itself gave us the [Hosting extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/) where you can avoid such things

Comment: Another option is to use `Span` inside `Label` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#formatted-text